# ADUser Attributes

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Is there another easier way to set-aduser attributes?

```
$User = "Please enter a username"
$streetAddress = "555 south"
$city = "New York"
$state = "US"
$postalCode = "55555"
$country = "United States"


Set-aduser -identity $User -Replace @{streetAddress=$streetAddress}
Set-aduser -identity $User -Replace @{l=$city}
Set-aduser -identity $User -Replace @{st=$state}
Set-aduser -identity $User -Replace @{postalCode=$postalCode}
Set-aduser -identity $User -Replace @{co=$country}
```

Comment: You can put it all in one replacement hashtable and run `Set-ADUser` once. Aside from that you might need to clarify on what you mean by "easier"

Comment: I'm not familiar with hastables. Can you show me an example?

Comment: See [example 3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/set-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps#example-3-set-properties), it's doing it for 2 attributes `title` and `mail`

Comment: ohh ok i see now. ok got it thanks

Set-aduser -identity $NewUser -Replace @{streetAddress=$streetAddress;l=$city;st=$state;postalCode=$postalCode;co=$country;c=$CountryRegionField}

Comment: Correct :) `;` or a new line for each attribute works fine up to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two easier alternatives, both using [Splatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.2).

This is the easiest by far, in this case [`Set-ADUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/set-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps) gives us friendly Parameter Names and facilitates the translation to their LDAP Display Name behind the scenes. For the AD Attributes being used in the question, luckily, all are available:

```
$params = @{
    Identity      = "the user here"
    City          = "New York"
    StreetAddress = "555 south"
    State         = "US"
    PostalCode    = "55555"
    Country       = "United States"
}

Set-ADUser @params
```

This one is doing the exact same thing however here we are actually using the attributes LDAP Display Name ourselves in the [replacement hash](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/set-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps#-replace):

```
$params = @{
    Identity = "the user here"
    Replace  = @{
        l  = "New York"
        co = "United States"
        st = "US"
        postalCode    = "55555"
        streetAddress = "555 south"
    }
}

Set-ADUser @params
```